Visual Studio Command Window Auto Completes when Period is Pressed
In the Command Window, I'm trying to type a path. As I type, I'm getting suggestions.  When I type a period (.), the top suggestion is chosen, which I don't want to happen; I want to finish typing the name of the file.  I can't find the setting that lets me turn off this poorly-chosen-hotkeyed feature; anyone know how to make typing a period, just type a period?  I would like a way to auto-complete; like pressing tab or some other reasonable key.  However, the important feature is typing period gives me a period in the Command Window.
For example: In my C-drive, I have 2 files

web - Copy.config
web.config

In the Command Window I type:

Tools.DiffFiles C:\web

I want to finish typing "web.config" but when I type the period, I get this

Tools.DiffFiles "C:\web - Copy.config"

When I delete the part, I don't want, typing period just auto completes to the wrong file, again.

Folders can’t have periods in them, have you thought, of changing the name of the folder?


These are filenames; none of the paths include folders.
While I have a specific problem, files commonly have periods in their names, and I foresee this being an issue in the future.

